Display share with geom_rect (proportional bar chart)
I have a dataframe that contains the share of observations for each color (orange, red, green, and yellow) per month.
structure(list(orange_pct = c(100, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), red_pct = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    green_pct = c(0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
    100, 100, 100), yellow_pct = c(0, 50, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), xmin = structure(c(18931, 18959, 18987, 19022, 
    19050, 19078, 19113, 19141, 19169, 19204, 19232, 19260, 19323
    ), class = "Date"), xmax = structure(c(18959, 18987, 19022, 
    19050, 19078, 19113, 19141, 19169, 19204, 19232, 19260, 19323, 
    18992), class = "Date"), Date = structure(c(18931, 18959, 
    18987, 19022, 19050, 19078, 19113, 19141, 19169, 19204, 19232, 
    19260, 19323), class = "Date")), class = c("rowwise_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), groups = structure(list(
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
        10L, 11L, 12L, 13L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))

I have another dataframe that contains the total count of observations, regardless of the colour, also per month.
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18931, 18959, 18987, 19022, 
19050, 19078, 19113, 19141, 19169, 19204, 19232, 19260, 19323
), class = "Date"), level = c("total", "total", "total", "total", 
"total", "total", "total", "total", "total", "total", "total", 
"total", "total"), value = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

I want to create a plot and display the share for each color using geom_rect and the count of observations with geom_line. So far, I've made a plot but geom_rect just displays the percentage for the colour orange, since I do not know how to display more variables per month.
I would like to display the share of colors for each month using geom_rect. I was also thinking about a stacked geom_bar, but I prefer geom_rect.
ggplot(df_long2, aes(x = Week, y = value)) +
  geom_rect(data = df_weekly, 
            aes(fill = orange_pct, xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, 
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), alpha = 0.2, inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
  geom_line(colour = "#231EDC") + 
  theme_minimal()

And this is my current result:


The variables in your data example do not quite match the code of the plot. Assuming that the first table refers to df_weekly and the second table to df_long2, and that Week is derived from Date (but for the exercise I'm going to use Date). What I think you're looking for is the following.
The first thing is that you must create a variable that groups the observations by color and then use that variable in the fill argument
# libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

df_weekly <- df_weekly %>%
  # Create group var
  pivot_longer(cols = orange_pct:yellow_pct, names_to = "name", values_to = "value")

# Match names with colors
legend_colors <- c("orange_pct" = "orange3", "green_pct" = "green3", "yellow_pct" = "yellow3", "red_pct" = "red3")

ggplot(df_long2, aes(x = Date, y = value)) +
  geom_rect(data = df_weekly_rect, 
            # Use group variable for fill
            aes(fill = name, xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, 
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), alpha = 0.2, inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
  geom_line(colour = "#231EDC") + 
  # Set the manual fill scale with predefined colors
  scale_fill_manual(values = legend_colors) +
  theme_minimal()

The output:

